# Django form accessing other data

Tags: django, forms, formset

I have a standard modelform and specify the fields I wish to render.

Is it possible to show data contained within that same model but not in the allowed fields in the template, and not as a form field just a string? Just using a normal template tag?

For example if I had a model like:

```
class Blah(models.Model):
     blah = models.CharField()
     blah_again = models.CharField()
```

And a form like:

```
class BlahForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blah
        fields = ['blah']
```

But in the template I want to render blah_again?

I am using model formsets and whilst I believe the principal to be the same, as 2 forms are rendered I need to title each form by a field in each model instance for logic presentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Instantiate the form then you can access the model through `form.instance`